# gnuplot: how to make x y axis without xtics and ytics

Tags: gnuplot

I am using gnuplot to draw something. 
 
And by default there will be tics on the axis, but I don't need these tics. How to remove them? 
I search some manual about the usage of `set xtics`, but did not find any clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just issue the command **unset xtics** and **unset ytics** to remove tics from both x and y axis.